# style file is not included in php laravel

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

I connect bootstrap, but laravel cant find styles
app.blade.php:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="={{csrf_token()}}">
    <title>@yield('title-block')</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public/css/style.css">


</head>
<body>
@yield('content')

</body>
</html>

<?php
```

registration.blade.php:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('title-block')
    Регистрация
@endsection

@section('content')

    <div class="container">
        <h1 align="center">
{{--            <a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.jpg" alt="logo" class="home"></a>--}}
            Register
        </h1>
    </div>
    <hr>

    <form name="register" method="POST" action="{{route('user.registration')}}">
        @csrf

            <input class="text-input" type="text" placeholder="Enter your surname" name="surname" required>
            <input class="text-input" type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" name="name" required><br>

            <input class="text-input" type="text" placeholder="Enter your number" name="number" required><br>

        <input class="text-input" type="text" placeholder="Enter your father`s name" name="fathers_name" required>
        <input class="text-input" type="text" placeholder="Enter parent number" name="parents_number" required><br>

            <input class="text-input-full-width" id="password" name="password" type="password" required placeholder="Enter password"><br>



            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit" name="sendMe" value="1">Войти</button>



    </form>
@endsection
```

I am beginner and dont understand why laravel dont see styles.css. I have try this

but its doesn`t work.  I hope you can help me
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXITE.png)

Comment: I have try this

but its doesn`t work. <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >

Comment: where is your css folder exists?

Comment: startup/public/css/styles.css

Comment: You can always use `href="/css/bootstrap.css"`. The `public/` folder should not appear in any url

Comment: I use it <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="public/css/bootstrap.css">

Comment: bro check file name you have mention **styles.css** in `startup/public/css/styles.css` but in html you are using only **style.css**

Comment: startup is you project folder name. right?

Comment: I fixed it but still doesn't work

Comment: Yes, its project

Answer (score 1):

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: try cache clean `php artisan optimize`

Answer (score 0):

You can use simply `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/bootstrap.css">`

For Laravel

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.css')">
```

And Add `ASSET_URL="${APP_URL}"` in .env file.

Don't Forget to clear views & cache

```
php artisan view:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score 0):

I find answer. I can only use `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">` without "public/"